# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "_CBCentralManagerOptionShowPowerAlertKey", importing Appodeal in React Native

Tags: ios, xcode, linker, react-native, xcode-project

I'm trying to import Appodeal to my React Native iOS app, I followed this [Appodeal XCode Tutorial](http://www.appodeal.ru/sdk/documentation?utf8=%E2%9C%93&framework=20&integration=1&ads_positions%5B%5D=3&ads_type%5B%5D=3&to_generate=1)

So I met an error in linking, and found some existing ways to solve it, but none of which did help me.

**ERROR:**

[image]

So here is my "Link Binary With Libraries" list:

[image]

And here is my Compile Sources & Target Membership:

[image]

Bitcode disabled:

[image]

Other Linker Flags:

[image]

Architectures:

[image]

Appodeal dependencies in the root of my project:

[image]

And that's all I've changed, so any ideas on where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I should've added CoreBluetooth.Framework (they missed it probably in the tutorial or whatever), now it's nice.

Found my answer here: groups.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/… ( Thanks Jaap ! )

And also I added libs with this instructions by SleepyViking from (https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/4572):

1. Go to Build Phases >Link Binary with Librairies > + > Add other
2. Once in the file selection window do "CMD"+Shift+G (Go to folder) and type /usr/lib/
3. From /user/lib you can add : libz.dylib and more...
4. Compile and have fun

Comment: anyway guys, it didn't work for me :(
I gave up several days later in infinite tryings to make things work..